# Shadow Box on Button staying over inactive html page

Tags: css, html

I have used CSS from a website to create a horizontal navigation bar in my page.
But, the problem is on the navigation bar, the first link is always shadowed even though, some other page is selected.

When I hover on some other link in navigation bar, it shows the shadow box, but never stays after i have clicked it.

Please tell me how to solve this, if you know.

```
CSS

/* Base Styles */
#nav ul,
#nav li,
#nav a {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
#nav {
  border: 1px solid #133e40;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
#nav ul {
  zoom: 1;
  background: #36b0b6;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #36b0b6), color-stop(100%, #2a8a8f));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #36b0b6 0%, #2a8a8f 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@top-color', endColorstr='@bottom-color', GradientType=0);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#nav ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#nav ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#nav li a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 15px 9px 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#nav li.active {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #36b0b6;
}
#nav li.active a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #1e6468;
  border: 1px solid #133e40;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
}
#nav li:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #36b0b6;
}
#nav li:hover a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #1e6468;
  border: 1px solid #133e40;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
}
```

Page

On Hovering over another link

[image]

After Clicking on Link, shadow box moves back to first link

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide some HTML code (preferably using a JSFiddle so we can play around with some code)? This way we can actually manipulate the code in a "sandboxed" environment instead of speculating a "possible" reason.

Comment: Ok, I will add some code

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle, but I was only able to add one page there. http://jsfiddle.net/ck766/1/

Comment: The fiddle link is missing ; )

Comment: oh sorry! Now, I have included, please check.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to load content in the same page when the user clicks a link or a new page is loaded?

Comment: a new page is being loaded.

Comment: And are you changing the `class='active'` in the menu to the adequate `li` or is it in every page applied to the "About" link?

Comment: I haven't used the concept of class='active'. So, do you mean I have to assign classes to each page and then make the one active which is in use right? but where can I make it active in HTML anchor tag?

Comment: Take a look to my answer, I explain this there. And yes, you're user the class active at least in two CSS rules(`#nav li.active` and `#nav li.active a`) and in the "About" li HTML (`<li class='active'>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple classes problem, I think:
When you're in the "About" page (let's pretend its filename is "about.html") you apply a class to the active link:

```
<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
<li><a href='academics.html'><span>Courses</span></a></li>
```

So, in the "academics.html" page, you have to remove the class from "About" and assign it to the current page, "Courses". So:

```
<li><a href='about.html'><span>About</span></a></li>
<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Courses</span></a></li>
```

And so on with every link and page.

**EDIT:**
Take a look, this would be the "Courses" page: http://jsfiddle.net/ck766/2/

Comment: You're welcome, I've been a web techs teacher for the last seven years and this is a very common mistake ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the same css that you use for :hover selectors also to active selectors,

```
#nav li:active {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  etc..
```

Active selector definition: *A link becomes active when you click on it.*

So just give the :active same css, or comma seperate the classes so you don't have to waste so much space.

```
#nav li:hover, #nav li:active {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  etc..
```

Comment: It is still not working, same result. It just shadows on hovers, once i click that link, it disappears.

Comment: Because you navigate away from the current page to another page (judging by your jsfiddle), then it can't remember what you clicked indeed. In that case you have to get current's active page somehow with php or whatever server side language you are using and give it a class active.

Comment: Oh, so is there is no way to do it with HTML/CSS. I haven't worked much in PHP. Can you illustrate how you mean the same in PHP, just basic outline